# LINQ Multiple "||" with "&" operator

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following Linq query trying to filter a collection of results that meet certain conditions as follows:

```
public async Task<BillListResponse> GetStudentCurrentBillsAsync(Student student)
    {
        var studentEvents = student.StudentEvents;
        var studentServices = student.StudentServices;
        var studentGroups = student.StudentGroups;

List<Bill> currentBills = await _context.Bills
            .Include(b => b.Category)
            .Where(b => ((b.ClassBills.Any(c => c.StudentClassId == student.ClassId)) || studentGroups.Any(sg => sg.SpecialGroupId == b.GroupId) || studentServices.Any(ss => ss.SpecialServiceId == b.ServiceId) || b.CareerPathBills.Any(cpb => cpb.CareerPathId == student.CareerPathId)) && b.SessionId == currentSession.Id
                ).ToListAsync();
......
```

But I keep getting the following error

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>   .Where(b => DbSet
>   .Where(c => EF.Property>(b, "Id") != null && EF.Property>(b, "Id") == EF.Property>(c, "BillId"))
>   .Any(c => c.StudentClassId == __student_ClassId_0) || __student_StudentEvents_1
>   .Any(se => (Nullable)se.EventId == b.EventId) || __student_StudentGroups_2
>   .Any(sg => (Nullable)sg.SpecialGroupId == b.GroupId) || __student_StudentServices_3
>   .Any(ss => (Nullable)ss.SpecialServiceId == b.ServiceId) || DbSet
>   .Where(c0 => EF.Property>(b, "Id") != null && EF.Property>(b, "Id") == EF.Property>(c0, "BillId"))
>   .Any(c0 => (Nullable)c0.CareerPathId == __student_CareerPathId_4) && b.SessionId == __currentSession_Id_5)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

which I have not been able to resolve.
However, I realized that if remove the "||" clauses in the expression, as follows:

```
List<Bill> currentBills = await _context.Bills
            .Include(b => b.Category)
            .Where(b => b.ClassBills.Any(c => c.StudentClassId == student.ClassId) && b.SessionId == currentSession.Id
                ).ToListAsync();
```

it works but I need more conditions as expressed in the full expression.

I am running on ASP.NET-Core 3.1 on Windows with SQL Server Database.

I seems I am getting something wrong with the "||" operator.

Please guide me to resolve this. I will appreciate.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

---

The entity relationships are as follows:

The student entity has the following

```
public virtual ICollection<StudentGroup> StudentGroups { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<StudentService> StudentServices { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<StudentEvent> StudentEvents { get; set; }
```

And the following DbSets exist too

```
public DbSet<StudentGroup> StudentGroups { get; set; }
public DbSet<StudentEvent> StudentEvents { get; set; }
public DbSet<SpecialService> Services { get; set; }
```

And the many-to-many intermediate tables are as follows

```
public class StudentEvent
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public SchoolEvent Event { get; set; }
}

public class StudentService
{
    public int SpecialServiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual SpecialService Service { get; set; }
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class StudentGroup
{
    public int SpecialGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual SpecialGroup SpecialGroup { get; set; }
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

---

UPDATE

I have modified the query as follows and it seems to be working now.

```
var studentEvents = student.StudentEvents.ToList();
var studentServices = student.StudentServices.ToList();
var studentGroups = student.StudentGroups.ToList();

List<Bill> bills = await (from b in _context.Bills where b.ClassBills.Any(c => c.StudentClassId == student.ClassId) || (studentEvents.Any() && studentEvents.Any(se => se.EventId == b.EventId)) || (studentGroups.Any() && studentGroups.Any(sg => sg.SpecialGroupId == b.GroupId)) || (studentServices.Any() && studentServices.Any(ss => ss.SpecialServiceId == b.ServiceId)) || b.CareerPathBills.Any(cpb => cpb.CareerPathId == student.CareerPathId) select b).ToListAsync();
```

---

Another way that seems to work as expected is the following

```
var studentEvents = student.StudentEvents.ToList();
var studentServices = student.StudentServices.ToList();
var studentGroups = student.StudentGroups.ToList();

var currentBills = _context.Bills
            ?.Include(b => b.Category)
            ?.Include(b => b.ClassBills)
            ?.Include(b=>b.CareerPathBills)
            ?.Where(b => b.SessionId == currentSession.Id);

        if (student.StudentEvents.Any())
        {
            currentBills = currentBills.Where(b => student.StudentEvents.Any(se => se.EventId == b.EventId));
        }

        if (student.StudentServices.Any())
        {
            currentBills = currentBills.Where(b => student.StudentServices.Any(se => se.SpecialServiceId == b.ServiceId));
        }

        if (student.StudentGroups.Any())
        {
            currentBills = currentBills.Where(b => student.StudentGroups.Any(se => se.SpecialGroupId == b.GroupId));
        }

        var currentBillsList = await currentBills.ToListAsync();
```

And

```
currentBillsList
```

is the expected result to return

I am not sure whether or not this is the right approach.

Comment: Check your parenthesis.

Comment: FYI `a || b && c` is translated as `a || (b && c)`, not `(a || b) &&c` - my rule when combining conditions with AND and OR: *always* use parentheses to specify precedence

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, I have done that but the problem still persists. I have updated my question to reflect how I have added the parenthesis to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is failing is that the `students` collection might not be part of SQL query for database tables, i.e. when calling `ToList` or `ToListAsync` it is becoming C# entities collection and will not work with LINQ to Entities collections.

**Hint**: make sure that your `students` are collections of `IQueryable`.

However, as an alternative suggestion here, you can use `Join` Students and Bills, instead of using filtering in the `Where` clause.

Comment: student is a variable fetched already from another query from the Database earlier before this particular query. student.events is expected to be a collection. Is that a wrong way to go about it?

Comment: I suggest you first get the data for the part before `||` operator, then convert it to list and after apply the second filtering part. I suspect that the student is not being able to be fit in that current context, because it either is not `IQuerable` or the query is becoming too complex for LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Each student actually has navigation properties on the following properties that exist as database tables. The following database tables actually exist - StudentEvents, StudentServices,StudentGroups. These are many-to-many relationship tables. I have updated my question to indicate those relationships and DBSets

Comment: As written the query would require sending a client-side collection of entities `studentEvents` to the server for evaluation.  EF can't do that.  it can send a collection of scalar values, but not Entities.

Comment: @Josh your error is saying that you are trying to use operations over the entities outside of the database context. That can happen if you use any operations like `ToList`, `ToListAsync` etc. or use methods not convertible to the database selectors. Please revisit your code and make sure that your collections were not converted to the `List`.

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan, Those are actually ICollections of entities as pointed out by David Brown.

Comment: @Josh, simply you can not convert a result of one query to anything else and later use the converted collection in another query. There above is saying about such a problem. If you want please provide me some level of access to your code and I will check that and get back to you.

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan, Could you look at the latest update I made to the code and see whether it makes sense because it seems to be working now though I don't know whether it is a good way to go about it

Comment: @Josh, it's certainly much better now. `Include` function is actually using SQL join underneath, so in your C# code above you are actually calling JOIN operation for the Tables, then checking the data amount and doing other logics, which seems fine for me.
Just FYI you can always check underneath generated SQL query when running program in Debug Mode, if you think that the query is fine that go ahead with your current solution. Btw you can always rewrite the same query with pure SQL if you think its not good from performance perspective.

Comment: @Josh, last question: only one of the above `if` statements will be true, yes? If so you can put the `if` statements under separate function, and return the collections, because currently even if the first `if` will return true, the other `if` statements will still execute, but you don't need that, right?

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan, I actually need to check the other conditions regardless of the outcome of the other ones.

Comment: @Josh ok, but I see that inside all conditions you are assigning the result to the same variable `currentBills`, which makes no sense because only the last assignment will work, all previous ones will be overridden.

Comment: OK. I  will review that. Thank you for taking time to review to such details.

Comment: Good, other than that everything else seems fine for me now )